# Determining if a jquery plugin has been initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using two different jquery plugins. selectpicker and prettyCheckable

neither return anything when I initialize them, so how can I determin if they are initialized so I don't re initialize them?

They get called like this

```
$("#StartTime").selectpicker();
$("input.terms").prettyCheckable();
```

I guess I could set a flag like this and check it very time I want to view the page and initialize the data in that page , but I don't know if that's the best way.

```
if (scope.isTermsInitialized === false) {
        $("input.terms").prettyCheckable();
        scope.isTermsInitialized = true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you loading jQuery properly? Consider moving these two lines into the jQuery document ready function. More info at https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Have you checked the console.log?

Comment: yes they are being loaded correctly but they exist on a form page that can be traversed forwards and backwards so they might be called multiple times. I need a way to check if they've been initiialized so I don't init them over and over. I guess I can set a flag and check the flag, but that doesn't seem correct!

Comment: @user1186050 that seems like a reasonable way to me

Comment: just wondering if there's a better way? I'm kinda new to Javascript and Jquery

Answer (score 0):

For the picker you can check the value of the get function.  I didn't see any methods for prettycheckable that would be of any use.  You could add some checks with the customClass method, but at that point you might as well set a variable.

http://picker.adam-uhlir.me/

http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/